# appcelerator titanium -TableViewRow selectedBackgroundColor remove rounded corners

Tags: javascript, iphone, user-interface, titanium, appcelerator

How do you overwrite the default style of the iPhone UI for selecting a row in a table view?
For the iPhone it is default blue, and can be changed with `TableViewCellSelectionStyle`, but that is limited to three choices. The alternative is to use `selectedBackgroundColor` in which I can pick any colour **BUT** gives rounded corners on the first and last rows in the table, which I do not want.

At the moment my workarounds are either to add extra dummy rows at top and bottom, or increase the table width to 340 to hide parts off screen. **Is there a method that simply removes the rounded corners?**

**borderRadius:0 has no effect**

Comment: is the Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle set? Setting it to PLAIN may remove the corners but it may also remove some of the styling you prefer to keep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the style to:

```
style: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.PLAIN
```

and that will remove any rounded corners

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Weird thing is I just went back to that project to see if this would solve it, but it no longer happens! not in any of my demo apps where they were rounded before. Between then and now I have completely uninstalled xCode and Titanium so I guess something was acting up somewhere.